# So do you want fancy hats this December?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

So I want to discuss with Hinduism community of what do they think about Winter Bash event?

If you are a year old user you probably know what Winter Bash is, for new users, Winter Bash is an event which gets started in mid December by Stack Exchange which lets you earn Hats just like you earn badges by participating in various activities on the website i.e by answering, questioning, awarding bounties etc.

You can wear those earned hats on your profile picture. Note that these hats are not permanent. We can use these hats on profile pictures only till the event is going on, later these hats will disappear from your profile page. Also, visitors won't see those hats unless and until they login to the website.

Some of the hats which were awarded in one of the previous Winter Bash event..

[image]

So I would like to have some comments over this so that we can forward these to Stack Exchange team.

If you want to check out old Winter Bash page - http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am eagerly waiting for my hat :)